# Using Arquillian Drone with Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, functional-testing, selenium-grid, jboss-arquillian, arquillian-drone

I have created a suite of functional UI tests for my web based application using Arquillian Done which I would like to run on a Selenium Grid as opposed to running them locally.

The problem I've got that despite setting the host/port details for the Selenium hub server in the `arquillian.xml` file, the UI tests are executed locally rather than on one of the Selenium nodes. I've even tried entering the details for a host that doesn't exist but the tests are still run locally and there are no error messages generated. It appears as though Drone is ignoring the configuration in the `arquillian.xml` file.

Is there something wrong with my configuration in the `arquillian.xml` file, or is there something else I'm doing wrong? Unfortunately there seems to be very little documentation on using Arquillian Drone with Selenium Grid.

The content of the `arquillian.xml` file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

  <extension qualifier="webdriver">
    <property name="browser">${arquillian.browser}</property>
    <property name="remoteAddress">http://selenium-hub:4444</property>
  </extension>

   <extension qualifier="selenium-server">
     <property name="host">selenium-hub</property>
     <property name="port">4444</property>
     <property name="skip">true</property>
   </extension>

  <container qualifier="arquillian-glassfish-remote">
    <configuration>
      ...
    </configuration>
  </container>

</arquillian>
```

My Maven pom.xml file contains the following dependency and dependencyManagement sections:

```
<dependencies>
  <!-- Various Java EE and Internal Dependencies -->

  <!-- Test Dependencies -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.graphene</groupId>
    <artifactId>graphene-webdriver</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8.Final</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-bom</artifactId>
      <version>2.46.0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-drone-bom</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.1.Final</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears there were two issues preventing the Arquillian Drone tests being executed against a Selenium Grid.

The first issue is that the `webdriver` section of the `arquillian.xml` file needs to include either `<property name="remote">true</property>` or `<property name="remoteReusable">true</property>` in addition to the `remoteAddress` property. Without either the `remote` or `remoteReusable` then the tests will be run locally.

The second issue was that the `remoteAddress` did not contain the full URL for the Selenium Grid hub server. The property should be set to `<property name="remoteAddress">http://selenium-hub:4444/wd/hub</property>`. Obviously `selenium-hub` needs to be set to the hostname of your Selenium hub server. What through me was accessing this URL via a browser returned a `NullPointerException` however this appears to be normal behaviour as there are other parameters set when the URL is accessed correctly.

In addition the `selenium-server` section of the `arquillian.xml` file appears to be unnecessary.